# Password protect single Drive

Tags: password, hard-drive

I have four drives. I want that whenever user tries to mount drive it should ask for password. I know password protecting ALL drives is possible through user previlages but I dont want it for all drives. I want it for single drive.

Answer (score 1):

Well, i have a workaround of sorts, try using truecrypt? to just encrypt that one drive that you want!

Comment: TrueCrypt is not a workaround, it's *the* solution - so long as you care in the least about real security.

Comment: I don't want to risk the drive using truecrypt, It has too much important data. Any other solution please?

Comment: Why do you think that truecrypt is risky? I use it since 4 years ago for my personal data and it always worked right.

Comment: Of course truecrypt is quite safe to use, but you should back it up beforehand. You should always back up, and after you've done that, you should back up some more. :-) Truecrypt can't, as far as I know, convert a drive *in-place*, so you might as well try it out, leaving the original copy intact, to see if it is reliable before you delete the originals, having backed them up of course.